# Rails 3 form_for :remote => true does not submit via AJAX

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, ujs

I am trying to submit a form via AJAX. I figured this should be a simple thing, but it insists on posting as a regular form...

**update**

This form exists within another form, which is not AJAXified, or related? Would that cause a problem?

#### The error I get

> ArgumentError in LinkWidgetsController#create
>
> There was no default layout for LinkWidgetsController in
>   [/Users/victorstan/Sites/portrait/app/views,
>   /Users/victorstan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@portrait/gems/devise-1.5.1/app/views]

Relevant code:

#### routes

```
  resources :profiles do
    resource :link_widgets #this handles the form requests for create
    member do
      get 'new_link_widget' #this handles the form requests for new
    end
    resources :pages
  end
```

#### controller

```
class LinkWidgetsController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def create
    @link_widget = LinkWidget.new(params[:link_widget])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link_widget.save
        format.js { render :js => @link_widget, :status => :created, :layout => !request.xhr? }
      else
        logger.debug @link_widget.errors.inspect
        format.js { render :js => @link_widget.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

#### partial

```
%hr
= form_for [@profile, @link_widget], :remote => true, :format => :js do |f|  
  .field
    = f.label :provider
    = f.select(:provider, options_for_select(f.object.providers, f.object.provider))
  .field
    = f.label :link
    = f.text_field :link, size: 37, class: 'input-width'
  .field
    = f.label :title
    = f.text_field :title, size: 37, class: 'input-width'
    %div
      %small.form-help-text If you set an optional title, it will show up beside the icon as a link
  .field
    = f.label :order
    = f.text_field :order, size: 2
  - unless f.object.new_record?
    .field
      = f.label :delete
      = f.check_box :_destroy
  = f.hidden_field :profile_id
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save', class: 'right'
  .clear
```

Comment: jQuery loaded? csrf_token? Not using both Prototype and JQ?

Comment: jQuery is loaded of course. I think I would notice if it was not :) There are not javascript errors in the console. And no, who uses prototype? Jeeez! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you mean by `This form exists within another form`, you have nested form tags (something like the following):

```
<form> <!-- this is a standard form -->
    ...
    <form> <!-- this is the remote/AJAXified form -->
        ...
    </form>
    ...
</form>
```

The HTML specification does not allow nesting of form tags. You should move the inner form to another place in your document. If that's not possible, you could try to use two submit buttons inside a single form, and then take appropriate action based on which button was pressed (you can do that on the server).

Comment: I was afraid this might be the answer :) Although, the problem is not that the form and it's parameters aren't being submitted properly, but that they are submitted as regular (non-AJAX) post...